# How do I set a character limit in sweetalert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

```
    $(document.getElementById("buttonClicked")).click(function(e) {
    swal({
        imageUrl: "http://www.petdrugsonline.co.uk/images/page-headers/cats-master-header",
        title: "sentence: ",
        text: "0/140",
        type: "input",
        showCancelButton: true,
        closeOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnCancel: true,
    }, function(text) {

        if (inputValue.length > 140) {
            swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
        }
        // fire post
        $.post("/index.php", {
            img: finalDataURL,
            text: text
        }).done(function(data) {

        });

       });
    });
```

I want to modify it so that the text will update for each character typed inside the input (0/140 -> 1/140 -> 2/140 -> etc) and I want to make it so that if the user tries clicking submit and the # amount of characters they typed exceed 140, an error pops up.

Right now my code isn't doing any of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, SweetAlert doesn't have a character counter built in so you'd have to tweak the source code a bit to get what you want.

For the error, you were on the right track, just missing a few things and some logic:

```
...
function(text) {

    // check the length of "text" instead of "inputValue"
    // since that's what you're passing into the function

    if (text.length > 140) {
        swal.showInputError("You have exceeded 140 characters!");
        return false;
    } else {
       // Only try submitting once character count validation has passed
        $.post("/index.php", {
            img: finalDataURL,
            text: text
        }).done(function(data) {

        });
    }
 });
```